# How to create multiple graphs using 'for' loop in networkx and python?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, social-networking

I'm trying to create  multiple empty graphs using 'for' loop in networkx and python? I need a way to do it in some form of loops.

```
for x in range (0,4):
    K[x]=nx.Graph()
```

this is the error I get

```
----> 2     K[x]=nx.Graph()

TypeError: 'Graph' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer

```
K = {}
    for x in range (0,4):
    K[x]=nx.Graph()
    K[x].add_node(x)
    print (nx.info(K[x]))
```